# Presenting Confirmation Dialog with 2 different properties

Tags: swiftui

I want to present Confirmation Dialog with 2 different binding properties, something like this:

```swift
.confirmationDialog("", isPresented: $calendarViewModel.showingDeleteEventDialog || $remindersViewModel.showingDeleteReminderDialog) {
    Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
        switch detailType {
        case .reminder:
            remindersViewModel.deleteReminder()
        case .event:
            calendarViewModel.deleteEvent()
        }
    }
    Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) { }
} message: {
    Text("Are you sure you want to delete this \(correctName.lowercased())?")
}
```

I don't want to create 2 separate confirmation dialogs if it is possible. How can I bind 2 properties in one so if one of them is true dialog is opening up, and automatically when it's closed turn them into false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `confirmationDialog(_:isPresented:titleVisibility:presenting:actions:message:)` then you can supply the data for the dialog using the `presenting` parameter.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/confirmationdialog(_:ispresented:titlevisibility:presenting:actions:message:)-8y541) says:

> In order for the interface to appear, both isPresented must be true and data must not be nil.

What this means, is that you would need a boolean state variable for controlling the visibility of the dialog and another state variable for controlling the type of dialog. Although there would still be two state variables, you won't need any more than that, even if there would be more types.

Like this:

```swift
@State private var isPresenting = false
@State private var type: DetailType?

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 50) {
        Button("Show reminder confirmation") {
            type = .reminder
            isPresenting = true
        }
        Button("Show event confirmation") {
            type = .event
            isPresenting = true
        }
    }
    .confirmationDialog("", isPresented: $isPresenting, presenting: type) { detailType in
        Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
            switch detailType {
            case .reminder:
//                print("deleting reminver")
                remindersViewModel.deleteReminder()
            case .event:
//                print("deleting event")
                calendarViewModel.deleteEvent()
            }
        }
        Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) { }
    } message: { detailType in
//        Text("Are you sure you want to delete the \(String(describing: detailType))?")
        Text("Are you sure you want to delete this \(correctName.lowercased())?")
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course! I don't need 2 properties, just add one, because detailType already supplied, tnx!

Answer (score 3):

I would go with an enum with a computed property for this

```
enum ShowDialog {
    case deleteEvent
    case deleteReminder
    case none

    var showDialog: Bool {
        self != .none
    }
}
```

And then replace the two boolean properties you are using now with a single one of type `ShowDialog`